# converting long array into const char*

Tags: c++, char

I have an array of longs, let's say:

```
long longsArray [5] = {0, 22, 31, 6, 8}
```

What I would like to do is to convert this into a const char* variable but with having an access to each number separately.

```
const char* foo;
```

So const char* should look like "0223168". Now, how can I get e.g. number 31 from this? And any other value which has more than one sign? I tried the following code using stringstream:

```
    stringstream ss;
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        ss << longsArray[i];
        foo = ss.str().c_str();
        cout << foo[i];
        }
```

But now only first 5 signs of this const char* are visible. It is important for me to having an access to each long variable from const char* because the long array is created dynamically and can have various values.

Comment: A `long` is not a `char`, their length is not the same...

Comment: I return the question to you: given string `"0223168"` how could you know whether you intend it to be `[223, 168]` or `[2231, 68]`? The information just doesn't exist.

Comment: Sure but I thought that some shifting is possible here, but ok then, I'll try to cope with this